# Limiting Number of ticks in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Apologies for the really long set of questions.

I am trying to plot a graph in matplotlib. I was faced with this issue of limiting the number of ticks on both of the axes. Looking into pyplot I could not find any solution.

The only solution I came across was by creating a subplot in the following manner.

```
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(4))
```

Although the above works, I am left with a few unsolved questions most of them in relation to how the matplotlib library is structured.

---

- Is there no feature whereby an object of pyplot.plot() can have
  the number of ticks limited. Do I have to always depend on
  subplotting?

---

- When i create an object `ax = plt.subplot(111)` I find that it
  creates an instance as below

  ```
  type(ax)
  Out[228]: matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot
  ```

Why does the documentation say that the subplot method returns a class ---> axes.SubplotBase

---

- Also I see that we need to use the xaxis attribute of ax(is it a method) which helps set the property related to the ticks.

  ```
  type(ax.xaxis)
  Out[233]: matplotlib.axis.XAxis
  ```

When ax is an object of some subclass of `matplotlib.axes` (not sure if it is `SubplotBase` or `AxesSubplot`) how come we can refer to `ax.xaxis`. The `xaxis` (or `axis.Xaxis`) attribute is not mentioned under to documentation of the `matplotlib.axes`.

---

I am pretty confused over the hierarchy and structure of matplotlib. It would be be helpful if someone can point me to an article or blog which details the structure of these features.

Looking through the documentation I could not figure out a suitable attribute of the subplot class which could help solve this problem related to number of ticks. I am not sure how I am going to solve the next problem if I cant go through the documentation and figure it out.

Thanks,

Sree